# Implement for transforming rotation matrix to rotation vector in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, camera-calibration, coordinate-systems

I want to implement the function for rotation matrix to rotation vector in pytorch. I have read the document in opencv tutorial [Rodrigues](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac) and refer the code in c [Rodrigues in c](http://read.pudn.com/downloads750/sourcecode/graph/opencv/2988718/Rodrigues/RodriguesTest.cpp__.htm). The transformation for rotation vector to rotation matrix is straightforward according to the formulation, but the reverse is obscure and undirect.
Is there any implement for the code in pytorch or any guide for implement this by myself?

Comment: can you add an explicit reference to the opencv method you refer to in your question?

Comment: sorry, I have add some explicit notes just now.